# How to connect AWS secret manager using VPC endpoint in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-secrets-manager

I want to connect my application to AWS secret manager using VPC endpoint (`vpce-098lnz0211f9f045g-madxscbm.secretsmanager.eu-west-1.vpce.amazonaws.com`) in .NET Core. My below code works fine when my application directly access AWS secret manager without VPC endpoint(via internet)

```cs
public string Get(string secretName){
    AmazonSecretsManagerConfig  config = new AmazonSecretsManagerConfig { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1 };
    AmazonSecretsManagerClient client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(accessid, secretkey, config);
    SecretsManagerCache cache = new SecretsManagerCache(this.client);
    var secret = cache.GetSecretString(secretName);
    return secret;
}
```

since there is no internet access on server and  I am new to AWS I require help in connecting my .NET Core application to AWS secret manager using VPC endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string Get(string secretName){
    AmazonSecretsManagerConfig  config = new AmazonSecretsManagerConfig { ServiceURL = "https://vpce-098lnz0211f9f045g-madxscbm.secretsmanager.eu-west-1.vpce.amazonaws.com" };
    AmazonSecretsManagerClient client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(accessid, secretkey, config);
    SecretsManagerCache cache = new SecretsManagerCache(this.client);
    var secret = cache.GetSecretString(secretName);
    return secret;
}
```